# Drupal youtube integration

Tags: drupal, video, upload, youtube

I have created a (ytd) channel for my site already but i have no idea how to access through drupal. My questions are

1. Is there any module that uploads user submitted videos to youtube (ytd) channel .
2. I need to edit user uploaded video and then submit to my ytd channel.

   please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Media youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) along with [Media mover](http://drupal.org/project/media_mover).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are modules for this the [embedded media field module](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) or the [media module](http://drupal.org/project/media), along with the [media:youtube module](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) can solve your problems, I did a tutorial on doing exactly what you need can be found at: http://gleamly.com/article/setup-video-your-drupal-website-using-media-and-mediayoutube

Comment: Your tutorial doesn't do exactly what he wants. Your tutorial shows how to utilise a video already uploaded to youtube, not how to upload a video to youtube via a Drupal field.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this module. Its a youtube uploader module a very light weight.

http://drupal.org/sandbox/sunnyuff/1874604

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a module just for this. [Media: Youtube Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube_upload). It's still being actively developed. A stable release should be ready by november 2015. If this suits your needs and you would like some additional features I'm happy to see your requests in the issue queue.